# Get download link in IPackage of Nuget Core

Tags: c#, nuget

I found example code to work with nuget api.
My task is show full name and download link.
Here is code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ID of the package to be looked up
            string packageID = "EntityFramework";

            //Connect to the official package repository
            IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");

            //Get the list of all NuGet packages with ID 'EntityFramework'       
            List<IPackage> packages = repo.FindPackagesById(packageID).ToList();

            //Filter the list of packages that are not Release (Stable) versions
            packages = packages.Where(item => (item.IsReleaseVersion() == false)).ToList();

            //Iterate through the list and print the full name of the pre-release packages to console
            foreach (IPackage p in packages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.GetFullName()};");
            }
        }
```

When I debug, I see link to download, but how can I get this value?
I attached screens for debug info.
[Debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBu2W.png)

[Missing param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhjBQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to get the link to download :

```
foreach (var p in packages.ConvertAll(o => (DataServicePackage)o))
                {
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.GetFullName()};");
    Console.WriteLine(p.DownloadUrl.ToString())
}
```

Comment: 'IPackage' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadUrl' and no extension method 'DownloadUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'IPackage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) GetNuget c:\...\GetNuget\Program.cs 31 Active. Please look at second screen. There are no DownloadUrl method.

Comment: You can cast your packages as DataServicePackage which is an implementation of IPackage interface. I have edited the answer above. Let me know if this works